# change permissions using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a setup.py file that contains:

```
  data_files=[(path.join(path.expanduser("~")), [path.join('libtools', "libfile.txt")])],
```

running

```
  sudo python setup.py install
```

works fine but when in the application, I try to modify libfile.txt, I get:

```
  can not write updated configuration to file at '/Users/home/libfile.txt': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/home/libfile.txt'
```

Is there a way of changing the permissions on "libfile.txt" using the setuptools? I tried passing the "--user" flag which works but then I can't call my program directly - i.e. "progname --arg" since it's not installed as root.